# how to access the value inside array of array

Tags: arrays, angularjs

If I have a format of array like this:

```
$scope.test = [
              ["Invalid Image","file size is invalid"],
              [],
              [],
              [],
              []
           ]
```

How can I get and display the array with value only. For example:

```
           Invalid Image
           file size is invalid
```

Is it possible?

Comment: `$scope.test[0][0]` will return `'Invalid Image'`

Comment: hmm I need to loop with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your using angular'js , you can use Angular's ng-repeat directive as below

**Template**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="name in names">
        <p>{{name[0]}}</p>
        <p>{{name[1]}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**controller**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

    app.controller('myCtrl',myCtrl);


    myCtrl.$inject = ["$scope"];

    function myCtrl($scope){

       $scope.names = [
            ["Invalid Image1","file size is invalid1"],
            ["Invalid Image2","file size is invalid2"]
       ] 

    }
```

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/w6duxj9h/

Answer (score 0):

You can do a nested iteration.

```
$scope.test.forEach(function(item) {
  var isArray = item instanceof Array;

  if(isArray) {
    item.forEach(function(value) {
      console.log(Value);
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

it depends on how you want to display it in view.
for example if you need to display it like list

use directives in your templates like ng-repeat

```
 <ul ng-repeat="tes in test">
<li ng-repeat="t in tes">{{ t }}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the previous answers, if you want to display only the arrays with 2 values like in your example, you can use the following:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div ng-show="item.length == 2" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
        {{item[0]}}<br/>
        {{item[1]}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/20052/